# How can I secure a toilet flange with damaged subfloor?

Tags: toilet, flange

The hole in the floor around the current pipe is larger than the damaged flange, so the replacement cannot be screwed to the floorboard.

Replacing that section of the floorboard would normally require attaching supporting boards to the joists. However, in this case there is only a 3" space between the floorboard and the connecting drain pipe (which runs parallel to the floor).

What can be done to secure the flange?

[image: Notice the connecting pipe]

This section of the bathroom did not have an underlayment. I created one (see photo). Would adding this board be enough support for the flange if grouted it and nailed it only to the subfloor? Thanks for all of the help and great suggestions.

[image: Would this option be a solution?]

Comment: A picture will help us see better what you have.  Quite sure someone here will have an idea if they can see the problem.

Comment: Three inches seems like more than enough space to put in some sort of support, at least based on the picture I'm able to create in my head of your situation. It seems, though, that my mental picture is wrong, so if you'd provide an _actual_ picture of your _actual_ situation, that would help everyone here help you.

Comment: I presume the 2nd picture with the brighter colored wood is the new piece of subfloor that you've added. Are you concerned that there isn't a joist near the drain and that this might cause issues with the wax seal between the toilet and flange? What is the actual concern?

Comment: The brighter colored wood is not a subfloor. It is a 1/4" piece laid on top of the subfloor.  This piece will make the floor even with the rest of the floor in the room. The question is whether screwing the flange to this piece and perhaps grouting it will be sufficient to adequately secure the toilet.

Answer (score 2):

Cut the existing flooring in the middle of the joist (well, put the edge of the wood you leave in the middle of the joist, to be picky about it by the width of a saw-kerf) and attach the replacement wood to the joist directly.

I agree with comments that 3" is more than plenty of space to attach additional support to the side of the joist, but if there's some reason you can't do that, flooring joints in new construction are made on top of a single joist ***all the time*** so there's no reason you can't make the replacement joint the same way.